# Implementing observer pattern without unsubscribe method

Tags: c++11, observer-pattern

When I implement observer pattern before, I always used to hold a reference to the owner inside of listener. And in listener's ctor I used register and in dtor I used to unregister.

But this time around I don't want to hold a reference for keeping weak coupling between this classes.

I come up with an [implementation with weak-ptr.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/w7PSwEkFO0qCj55u)  My question is, if it is ok to implement observer pattern without unsubscribe method with weak-ptr? 
Is there any case that I can get into trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a `weak_ptr` to an observer is a natural fit.

However, your implementation has a data race where `elem` expires during your loop, you probably want to instead do

```
for (auto elem : listenerList)
{
    auto locked = elem.lock();
    if (locked) { locked->update(val); }
    else { anyExpired = true; }
}
```